# how to build short code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want build a library function so  that when my text comes from database that function filter that text.

Ex : string message= " Hello, world";

so my one function will change the text hello to hi
and another function will change the world to global.

This filter only work if there is any function in my class.

I need this to do in asp.net c#. Is any one have the idea how to do this.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

Its not quite clear what you trying to achieve. 
But I think you want to do something like this...

```
var s = YOUR STRING
string[] wordslist = s.Split(' ');
foreach (var word in wordslist )
{
      switch (word )
      {
            case "Hello":
                word= word.replace(word,'Hi');
            case "World":
                 etc.....
      }     
}
```

I think it will  be much easier if you can create database table which hold pair of values.
eg

```
tblReplace
OldValue       NewValue
Hello          Hi
World          global
```

So you can do a search for each character with against the `OldValue` field and if found, you can replace the word with new value..

Hope this helps